# Twitter tweet button doesn't appear if twitter widgets script is present. why is this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I have a twitter tweet button and it shows absolutely no styling, as in it doesn't even appear. If i remove the  tag that goes with the  tag of the tweet button then the  tag shows and directs to a twitter page where you can tweet. But the button isn't styled and it doesn't have any of the styling of the typical tweet button.

Even if i go to publish.twitter.com/ and use a default button that they provide it doesn't work correctly.

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=LoveTwitter&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet #LoveTwitter</a>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

That is my HTML where a sample tweet button is from twitter. This doesn't show up at all so there isn't really any point in showing a screenshot of my page.

```
div#map{
width:100%;
height:100%;;
}

.location-form{
position: absolute;
width: 100vw;
z-index: 1000;
height: 100vh;
}

.col.align-self-center{
color: #909090;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 40px;
background-color: #303030;
}

#legend {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
background: #fff;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

#locationbox{
margin: 10px;
padding: 5px;
width: 50%;
}

.media{
border: 2px solid black;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 5px;
}

.no-padding{
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0;
}

.splash-page{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}

.home-top{
background: url("../images/home-topback.jpeg");
background-size: cover;
background-image: opacity(70%);
}

.carousel-item{
width: auto;
height: 320px;
}

.home-desc{
background-color: #EBDCB2;
}
```

That is my (badly formatted, sorry i don't know how to use the code tag) CSS if it helps.

Comment: It works fine for me. Maybe you are using ad-blocking extensions?

Comment: @Mordecai I just tried it in chrome and it seems to work there but not in Opera. Weird since they both use the same backend engine hmm